# ¿Existe un problema con las cookies de Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, bug

Desde hoy, sin importar que opción que seleccione, me aparace el "popup" para aceptar las cookies.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que navego a otra página, en los dominios:

- es.stackoverflow.com
- es.meta.stackoverflow.com

Me vuelve a salir dicho popup.

Comment: Encontre una solución y es ir a stackoverflow.com y aceptar ahí. Solo si acepto las cookies en dicho dominio el popup deja de aparecer.

Comment: Interesante. Uso un navegador que bloque las cookies y los pop-ups, entonces no me sale. ¿Quizás el dominio de la cookie es *.stackoverflow.com o algo por el estilo?

Comment: A mi me estuvo pasando hace algunas horas, y ahora se solucionó solo

Comment: A mi tambien me estuvo pasando la semana pasada. No se como se solucionó...

Comment: a mi no me pasan esas cosas por que suelo tener el navegador en modo efimero y cuando lo cierro se van a la porra las cookies viejas y solo pemanencen las importantes de secciones que maneja el mismo google account ...

Comment: Me está pasando en el telefono.